# Juju GUI Network Interface

Tags: networking, server, juju

When I've installed Juju-GUI service I need to see it's public address. When I type:

```
juju status
```

System gives me the following output:

```
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
agent-version: 1.16.3.1
dns-name: 10.0.3.1
instance-id: localhost
series: precise
  "1":
agent-state: started
agent-version: 1.16.3.1
instance-id: server-local-machine-1
instance-state: missing
series: precise
services:
  juju-gui:
charm: cs:precise/juju-gui-79
exposed: true
units:
  juju-gui/0:
    agent-state: pending
    agent-version: 1.16.3.1
    machine: "1"
    public-address: 10.0.3.214
```

And I see that my Public address is **10.0.3.214**, but my subnet is 10.0.**1**. and my local address is 10.0.1.49
I also noticed that after installing Juju, system added my strange network interface called:

```
lxcbr0
```

How can I change public address of service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running locally using LXC and the IP address you see is the IP address of the Juju GUI inside the LXC.  You cannot change it.

The `lxcbr0` interface is created by LXC.

From your host machine you should be able to access the GUI by going to `10.0.3.214` in your browser.

Comment: Can I access it from other computers?

Comment: No, unless you enable IP forwarding and set up some kind of routing  - it's a local network on the host machine.